# Touchpad scrolling is not working in my laptop

Tags: 14.04, touchpad, lenovo, scrolling

I am using Ubuntu 14.04 in my Lenovo B50-70 LAPTOP. But, scrolling in touchpad is not working.my laptop having Ps/2 Elantech touchpad id=12

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add output of `xinput; uname -r` terminal command.

Comment: Can you give the output of commands? And also output of `dmesg | grep pnp`

Answer (score -1):

I ran into the same problem but found a solution. Install this software by entering the following Synaptiks Touchpad command into the terminal.

sudo apt-get update

sudo apt-get install wget gdebi
wget http://http.us.debian.org/debian/pool/main/s/synaptiks/kde-config-touchpad_0.8.1-2_all.deb

sudo gdebi kde-config-touchpad_0.8.1-2_all.deb

Once the terminal is done doing its thing, type Synaptiks into the Unity dash and you'll see it come up, click on it and you can adjust the touchpad settings and enable vertical/horizontal scrolling. :)